# Challenges w.r.t. proximity between application hosted outside Amazon and Amazon persistence services (SimpleDB & S3)

Tags: performance, amazon-s3, topology, simpledb

This is about hosting a web portal. Earlier my topology was entirely based on Amazon AWS but the price factor (especially for EC2) now makes me re-think.

I'll now quickly come to what I have finally arrived at. I'll launch the portal that'll be hosted on Godaddy (unlimited plan on Windows). The portal uses SimpleDB for storing metadata and S3 for blobs. Locally available MySQL will be used for the ASP.Net provider services.

Once the portal is profitable, I intent to move to Amazon in totality.

Now considering the proximity between Godaddy & Amazon, would I face 'substantial' performance problems? Are there any suggestions to improve upon my topology.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on how your application uses SimpleDB and S3 internally.  Some thoughts:

- Amazon recommend firing requests in parallel at SimpleDB, so ensure your application is well architected to allow you to do this.  If you're making many queries serially, then your application performance will likely be dreadful, particularly due to the network latency.
- S3 buckets can be made accessible to the public, or you can use Amazon's CDN facility with S3, or you can generate time-limited URLs to a particular private resource.  If you're storing blobs of data, images etc that the user's browser could download directly, use these features rather than downloading them to your server and passing them back to the user.